# Draw on screen using C++

Tags: c++, windows, drawing

I'm trying to find a way to draw something on the screen using C++ that would always be on top, even over programs that are in fullscreen.

I want to do this in Windows 10 and so far I've found this https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=DirectDrawOverlayLib

Comment: Standard `c++` has no ability to draw. No concept of a screen or widgets or anything like that. You need a library or framework.

Comment: It would likely help to include which OS(es) need to be supported as well as where your own research has gotten you. I'm not sure if libraries support the fine-grained transparency features needed to do that in a cross-platform way.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows OS, you can get the device context of the screen then draw to this device. Here is an example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Drawing a line on screen during ten seconds ....\n"; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        MoveToEx(hdc, 0, 0, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, 1000, 1000);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```